# Common-Mode Voltage

Tags: differential, transmitter, common-mode

I have an application which is using a differential transmitter to transmit a video signal(PAL).Transmitter is placed in a remote device which is connected through a long cable.The device is powered  up through two conductors(one for 24V and one for GND) which each conductor has 1.8ohms.My doubt is if the device consumes 5 amps I will have a ground difference of about 9V, so from start the common mode voltage on the twisted pair of differential transmitter will be 9V.Is it true ?

Comment: Your wires will burn. Are you sure about the numbers?

Comment: Yes, cable has about 200m.It s normal his resistance.

Comment: In that case it's a crime to use 24V. Use 96, even 48. Just think, how much power you waste. As for the video, you must use isolated driver, so the gnd voltage will not matter.

Comment: I know I will change to 220V AC an decrease the voltage with a transformer.I just want to know if my assumption is correct about common mode voltage.

Comment: What about the receiver? Where is it, how is it powered?

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming* that the differential signals are generated relative to ground, then the answer would be yes, as seen from the other end.

The ground would have floated up by 9V relative to the supply's ground, and the 24V would float down by the same amount - leaving only 6V at the transmitter end.

Not actually relevant to the question asked, but do you really need 5 amps to power what sounds like a camera?  If so, you're going to need a higher voltage.

Comment: Well, this is a crawler for pipe inspection, so it is equipped with some type of motors for movement.I know that it is a waste of power but this was only a prototype.Right now I am changing the whole design, the power will be transmitted AC at 220V and in the crawler I will have a power transformer to step down the voltage.

Answer (score 0):

Well the receiver is powered from the start of wires, so the remote device is powered through that resistance of cable.The ground difference at 5 amps is 9V(1.8 * 5).The receiver is powered up from the same supply just that the resistance to ground is almost 0.

Sorry I wanted to be a comment.

Comment: Just use isolated supply to disconnect the gnd.

Comment: My question is if what I said is true ?If the common mode voltage of twisted pair is 9V.

Comment: Not necessarily. Depends on specific output stage.

Comment: Could you explain a little bit ?

Comment: The point of differential output is 4hat common mode component may change and it doesn't matter. So it may be 0 or 9v or 24v, the signal is in diff mode, s8 it doesn't matter. But i hardly believe that your output buffer has such wide range, and i also don't think that your receiver will live well with signal created 9V above.

Comment: Well, the output driver doesn't generate this 9V.This 9V appears because the GND wire has this resistance and when the load take some current, this current make the conductor to drop some voltage across it.So when you measure the difference between the sender and receiver even if the transmitter is in high impedance you will see this drop voltage across GND cable.

Comment: Trust me, i understand you completely. Which is why i suggest following my advices: use higher voltage, isolate your circuit from input voltage.

Comment: Thank you very much for understanding.Anyway I will do this to be  more efficient, I just wanted to prove my theory.

Comment: Look, having isolated power supply will allow you to ignore the voltage drop across the wires.